# Displaying arraylist of objects containing one attribute whose value is superior to a certain value

Tags: java

I am trying to display an arraylist of recordings for mountain climbing where the mountain height was superior to 5K.

I am invoking an object method getheight() from another class but every time I try to compile, I am told that double can't be dereferenced. what am I doing wrong here? is there a better way of displaying a arraylist of objects containing an attribute whose value is superior to a certain number in Java? I have a feeling that I am close but yet far off the target. any tips?

```
public void Displayrecording()
{
  double highestheights;
  for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
    if(highestheights.getheight() > 5)
    {    
      System.out.print(records.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your gethieght() method return a double?

Comment: yes, it returns a double. basically, the end goal is to print out all recordings where the mountain height was superior to to 5k

Comment: You cant invoke methods on a primitive data type. in the if condition just do a if(highestheights > 5)

Answer (score 0):

A `double` is just a number.  It does not have a height, or anything else.  It's just a number.

So all you need is `highestheights > 5`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but correct me if am wrong, are you suggesting that I declare a variable without any data type? would it be better if a set it as boolean?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that at all.  I'm saying that calling things like `getheight()` on a double makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If getHeight is going to give you altitude it looks you're looking for something like:

```
public void Displayrecording()
{
double highestheights;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  highestheights = /*maybe some static class here*/getheight(/*maybe some parameter here*/);
  if(highestheights > 5000)
    {    
    System.out.print(records.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Generally your code is missing an array with mountain names or ids.